# Unable to find method 'org.gradle.api.artifacts.result.ComponentSelectionReason.getDescription()Ljava/lang/String;'

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

This Is the error that it shows after compiling my app imported :
**Unable to find method 'org.gradle.api.artifacts.result.ComponentSelectionReason.getDescription()Ljava/lang/String;'.
Possible causes for this unexpected error include:
Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)

The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)

Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.

In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.**

**build.gradle**

```
    var = '4.0.1'
}

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.




buildscript {

    ext.versions = [
            'compileSdk'      : 30,
            'targetSdk'       : 30,
            'fragment'     : '2.3.5',
            'core'     : '1.6.0',
            'butterknife'     : '10.2.3',
            'constraint'      : '1.1.3',
            'dagger'          : '2.37',
            'espresso'        : '3.0.2',
            'glide'           : '4.12.0',
            'gson'            : '2.8.7',
            'junit'           : '4.13',
            'leakcanary'      : '1.6.3',
            'lifecycle'       : '1.1.1',
            'mockito'         : '1.10.19',
            'powerMockito'    : '1.6.2',
            'hamcrest'        : '1.3',
            'okhttp'          : '5.0.0-alpha.2',
            'retrofit'        : '2.9.0',
            'room'            : '1.1.1',
            'runner'          : '1.0.2',
            'rxandroid'       : '3.0.0',
            'rxjava'          : '3.0.13',
            'supportlibrary'  : '28.0.0',
            'timber'          : '4.7.1',
            'firebase'        : '22.0.0',
            'youtube'        : '2.1.0',
            'exoplayer'        : '2.11.7',
            'stringcare_version'        : '4.0.1',
    ]

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
            }
        maven {
            url 'https://android-sdk.is.com/'
        }

        maven { url 'https://artifacts.applovin.com/android' }

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        classpath "com.stringcare:plugin:${versions.stringcare_version}"
        classpath "com.applovin.quality:AppLovinQualityServiceGradlePlugin:+"

    }
}


allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'}
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven {
            url "https://artifactory.appodeal.com/appodeal"
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://android-sdk.is.com/'
        }
        maven {
            url "https://dl.appnext.com/"
        }


        maven {
            url  "https://cardinalcommerceprod.jfrog.io/artifactory/android"
            credentials {
                // Be sure to add these non-sensitive credentials in order to retrieve dependencies from
                // the private repository.
                username 'paypal_sgerritz'
                password 'AKCp8jQ8tAahqpT5JjZ4FRP2mW7GMoFZ674kGqHmupTesKeAY2G8NcmPKLuTxTGkKjDLRzDUQ'
            }
        }
        mavenLocal()



    }
}

ext.versions2 = [
        'api'            : 'https://api.envato.com/v3/',
        'api2'            : 'https://api.yobdev.live/easyplex/api/'
]


task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**app\build.gradle**

```
    var = '4.0.1'
}

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.




buildscript {

    ext.versions = [
            'compileSdk'      : 30,
            'targetSdk'       : 30,
            'fragment'     : '2.3.5',
            'core'     : '1.6.0',
            'butterknife'     : '10.2.3',
            'constraint'      : '1.1.3',
            'dagger'          : '2.37',
            'espresso'        : '3.0.2',
            'glide'           : '4.12.0',
            'gson'            : '2.8.7',
            'junit'           : '4.13',
            'leakcanary'      : '1.6.3',
            'lifecycle'       : '1.1.1',
            'mockito'         : '1.10.19',
            'powerMockito'    : '1.6.2',
            'hamcrest'        : '1.3',
            'okhttp'          : '5.0.0-alpha.2',
            'retrofit'        : '2.9.0',
            'room'            : '1.1.1',
            'runner'          : '1.0.2',
            'rxandroid'       : '3.0.0',
            'rxjava'          : '3.0.13',
            'supportlibrary'  : '28.0.0',
            'timber'          : '4.7.1',
            'firebase'        : '22.0.0',
            'youtube'        : '2.1.0',
            'exoplayer'        : '2.11.7',
            'stringcare_version'        : '4.0.1',
    ]

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
            }
        maven {
            url 'https://android-sdk.is.com/'
        }

        maven { url 'https://artifacts.applovin.com/android' }

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        classpath "com.stringcare:plugin:${versions.stringcare_version}"
        classpath "com.applovin.quality:AppLovinQualityServiceGradlePlugin:+"

    }
}


allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'}
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven {
            url "https://artifactory.appodeal.com/appodeal"
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://android-sdk.is.com/'
        }
        maven {
            url "https://dl.appnext.com/"
        }


        maven {
            url  "https://cardinalcommerceprod.jfrog.io/artifactory/android"
            credentials {
                // Be sure to add these non-sensitive credentials in order to retrieve dependencies from
                // the private repository.
                username 'paypal_sgerritz'
                password 'AKCp8jQ8tAahqpT5JjZ4FRP2mW7GMoFZ674kGqHmupTesKeAY2G8NcmPKLuTxTGkKjDLRzDUQ'
            }
        }
        mavenLocal()



    }
}

ext.versions2 = [
        'api'            : 'https://api.envato.com/v3/',
        'api2'            : 'https://api.yobdev.live/easyplex/api/'
]


task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**gradle-wrapper.properties**

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.2-all.zip
```

**gradle.properties**

```
# IDE (e.g. Android Studio) users:
# Gradle settings configured through the IDE *will override*
# any settings specified in this file.
# For more details on how to configure your build environment visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html
# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m 
android.nonTransitiveRClass=true
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.parallel=true

# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
# org.gradle.parallel=true
```

Comment: the network is operational and done

Comment: I got the same issue ugrading Capacitor to v3, I'll inform u, if I found sth working.

Answer (score 14):

I used the latest Android Studio version and the issue was solved.

Comment: It solved mine too! I think the 2021 version is much better.

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same issue with IntelliJ IDE. I was using 2019.x.x . After installing the latest version (2021.3.1) the issue is solved.

Answer (score 2):

Got the same issue, after migrating my Ionic project to Capacitor 3.
Solved it by installing the latest Android Studio version and Android SDK.
https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/4592

Comment: I unfortunately need my AS v3.5.3 because of an old plugin that does not work in higher versions of AS

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue by upgrading the intellij version to 2021.3.3